# empezado en c gracias

Tags: c, while, switch

Estoy intentando hacer un bucle `do while` de vocales que imprime si es vocal o no y cuando alguien ingresa la letra "z" el programa termina.

El problema es que me sale que algo es vocal y no es vocal al mismo tiempo. Me toma el defaul como mensaje también.

```c
/* Programa: Letra vocal */
#include <conio.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{ 
   char letra;
   int  acumulador, contador;

   acumulador = 0; 
   contador = 0;

   printf( "\n   Introduzca una letra: "); 

   do 
   {
      scanf( "%c", &letra);
      acumulador += letra; contador++;

      switch (letra) {
         case 'a':
            printf ("Es una vocal");
            break;
         case 'A': 
            printf ("Es una vocal");
            break; 
         case 'e':
            printf ("Es una vocal");
            break;
         case 'E':
            printf ("Es una vocal");
            break; 
         case 'i': 
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break;
         case 'I':
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break;
         case 'o': 
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break; 
         case 'O':
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break;
         case 'u':
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break; 
         case 'U':
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break;
         default: 
            printf ( "No es una vocal \n" );
            break; 
      }
   }
   while( letra != 'z' );
   
   getch(); /* Pausa */
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque está presionando 2 teclas.

1. La letra
2. Y el "enter" y este último no es vocal

Solución fácil, agregar un case con salto de linea:

```
   switch (letra) {
         case 'a':
            printf ("Es una vocal");
            break;
         case 'A': 
            printf ("Es una vocal");
            break; 
         case 'e':
            printf ("Es una vocal");
            break;
         case 'E':
            printf ("Es una vocal");
            break; 
         case 'i': 
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break;
         case 'I':
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break;
         case 'o': 
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break; 
         case 'O':
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break;
         case 'u':
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break; 
         case 'U':
            printf ("Es una vocal"); 
            break;
         case '\n':
            //Enter
            break;
         default: 
            printf ( "No es una vocal \n" );
            break; 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

Pon un espacio en tu `scanf()`, osea, `scanf(" %c", &letra);` para eliminar el problemático salto de línea que es el que activa siempre el `default`.

## Repuesta reducida

Puedes reducir tú código con:

```c
/* Programa: Letra vocal */
#include <stdio.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

int main() { 
   const char* VOWELS = "aeiouAEIOU";
   const int VOWELS_QTY = 10;

   char letra;
   int continue_game = TRUE;
   int is_vowel;
   int acumulador = 0;
   int contador = 0;
   char* result;

   printf("\nIntroduzca una letra: ");
   while (1) {  
      is_vowel = FALSE;
      scanf(" %c", &letra);
      acumulador += letra;
      contador++;

      if (letra == 'z')
         break;

      for (int i = 0; i < VOWELS_QTY; ++i) {
         if (VOWELS[i] == letra) {
            is_vowel = TRUE;
            break;
         }  
      }
      result = (is_vowel) ? "Is vowel": "Is not vowel";
      printf("%s\n", result);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Me sirvió Muchas gracias te lo agradezco!  Se me habían quemado los pelos jajaja :)

Comment: @ElArgento Alternativamente puedes consumir el salto de línea con [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar). Por cierto, si te sirvió la respuesta marcala cómo aceptada.